# Apply Spark distinct function on RDD of an object

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have `employee` object that contains the following information:

Name, age, id.

I used Spark to read data from file and created from the data employee objects.
Now I have `JavaRDD<employee>` and I want to remove duplicates.
My Employee class implements `boolean equals(Object other){...}`
I tried to use distinct function but it didn't work, I got the following error:

> java.io.NotSerializableException:

I'm using Spark 2.4.7

Comment: Sharing the code you've tried would make the question clearer and helps others to answer it.

Comment: please share code used.